# Encode audio and video in same format and then merge

Tags: ffmpeg, codec, mkv

I am using **ffmpeg** to create videos from images and mkvmerge to then merge these videos in a single video. I now found myself in a situation where I need to merge a video clip(with or without sound) in between these slides. Problem is if video clip has sound then mkvmerge is unable to merge the files since other slides don't have sound. I then decided to generate slide videos with silent sound( I created a silent sound mp3 file and use it when creating video from image). Now another problem arises which occurs when video clip does not have mp3 sound. In this case mkvmerge fails again and complaining about differnt audio format. I need help for ffmpeg command which converts all video parts in same audio and video format so I can use mkvmerge easily to merge the videos or **mkvmerge** command which allows me to merge files having different audio codec.

thanx

Answer (score 0):

> Now another problem arises which occurs when video clip does not have mp3
>   sound. In this case mkvmerge fails again and complaining about differnt audio
>   format. I need help for ffmpeg command which converts all video parts in same
>   audio and video format

```
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -c:a libmp3lame out.mkv
```